# How to use variables in a multi-project gradle build system?

Tags: java, gradle, build, multi-project

I have a multi-project structure managed with gradle. All the java sub-projects have this `jar` block:

```
def main_class = "foo.Main"
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': main_class
    }
}
```

So I decided that I'm going to move the jar block to the root project and have only the `def main_class` in the sub-projects, but no matter how I defined the `main_class` variable, it didn't work. I tried `project.ext` and `properties {}` as well.

I had a task, called `dist` which worked with `project.ext`:

root project:

```
subprojects {
    task dist(dependsOn: jar) << {
        copy {
            from('build/libs') {
                include (build_jar)
            }
            into('.')
            rename(build_jar, app_jar)
        }
    }
}
```

a sub-project:

```
project.ext {
    build_jar = "..."
    app_jar = "..."
}
```

How can I define a variable that works with `jar` like with the `dist` task?

Answer (score 3):

You can just do:

```
ext {
  main_class = 'com.Main'
}

subprojects {
  apply plugin: 'java'
  jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': main_class
    }
  }
}
```

in `PROJECT_ROOT/build.gradle` file.

Comment: Unfortunately, the value of `main_class` depends on the sub project

Comment: If this value can be kept in root build.gradle this is still doable.

Answer (score 1):

To override extra properties in subproject's build.gradle you must put your desired task (in this case the `jar task`) inside the `afterEvaluate` block.

root project build.gradle:

```
subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'application'

    ext {
        // the property that should be overridden in suproject's build.gradle
        main_class = ''
    }

    afterEvaluate {
        jar {
            manifest {
                attributes 'Main-Class': main_class
            }
        }
    }
}
```

sub project build.gradle:

```
mainClassName = 'project.specific.Main'
ext.set("main_class", mainClassName)
// you could also use this notation, but I prefer the first one
// since it is more clear on what it is doing
//main_class = mainClassName
```